# Can you avoid floating point errors in financial applications with Math.round(result * 100) / 100?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ive read about typescript number type is floating point and may result in errors when used in financial programs where numbers are represented to two decimal places.  I realize I  can use longs are represent everything in cents, but its tedious to do currency multiplication because $1.00 x $1.00 = $10.00 for example unless you remember to divide by 10^(n*2) where n is the number of currency factors.

I was thinking I could maybe just use something like:

```
let result = [some floating math with dollar amounts]
let answer1 = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
```

For my application which is dealing in $ amounts not to exceed say $100MM, it seems like it will suffice to errors like `$2.00 x 20% x 10% != $0.04` but I'm not sure this will work in all the cases that might produce similar errors when I am doing a lot of math on currency amounts in my application.

Comment: When does it ever make sense to multiply currency values together? What is a dollar^2?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/8186898

Comment: I understand the theoretical issue, but  have been unable to find a realistic example where Math.round(result*100)/100 yields an answer off by more then $0.01.  Seems a lot easier than dealing with BigInts

Comment: Mark Reed: In my case it came up in exchange rates if its stored in the DB as say, US$ per Swedish KR (about $0.10) So if you store those as integer pennies, and you want to convert, say KR150 you get '10' x '150000' .

Comment: Assumptions like your "For my application which is dealing in $ amounts not to exceed say $100MM" have broken financial software in the real world, for example during the Zimbabwe currency crisis, where hyperinflation peaked at a staggering 80000000000% per month. The amounts for even simple transactions became so high that it broke the datatypes used in the software. Just don't do it. Money is not a float, it is not an integer, it is money. The correct datatype to store money is `Money`. If your language's standard library doesn't have it (most don't), you need to write it.

Comment: "Just don't do it" sounds more like a religious conviction than an actual answer to my question.  I have a zimbabwe $10 Trillion note hanging on my wall.   I can also decide for myself the risks associated with hyperinflation on my app versus the effort and potential introduction of errors from engineering a new "money class".  None of it is really an answer to the question I posed.